# simple jq filter has null results

Tags: jq

I'm using the filter

```
[.bar_1.baz_a, .bar_1.baz_b, .bar_2.qux_1,.bar_2.qux_2]
```

on the following JSON and it's returning four nulls instead of two lines each having four elements of nonsense data.  This is my first attempt at a filter, what concept am I not comprehending?

```
{
  "version": "0.1",
  "foos": [
    {
      "bar_1": {
        "baz_a": 673396201,
        "baz_b": "dfgsfg"
      },
      "bar_2": {
        "qux_1": "ghjhj",
        "qux_2": "Q"
      }
    },
    {
      "bar_1": {
        "baz_a": 674567484,
        "baz_b": "tyutyj"
      },
      "bar_2": {
        "qux_1": "bnmn",
        "qux_2": "Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root object doesn't have keys `bar1` and `bar2`; those occur in the objects in the array assigned to the name `foos`. Compare your filter to

```
jq '.foos[] | [.bar_1.baz_a, .bar_1.baz_b, .bar_2.qux_1,.bar_2.qux_2]' tmp.json
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to do everything in one filter, when I should have been piping one in to the next.  As a bonus question, any idea why piping this result to join(",") fails?

Comment: You can only join JSON strings, but 674567484 is a JSON number.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'll look up how to convert a number to string.